# Фразу "Падает дождь" корректно ли использовать в русском языке?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология

- Правильно ли в русском языке говорить "Падает дождь"? Равнозначна ли эта фраза выражению "Идет дождь"?
- Такой же вопрос, равносильны ли фразы "Идет снег" и "Падает снег"?

[Падает дождь - песня](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MK4HXW79y4Q)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот доказательства корректности использования выражений "падает дождь" и "падает снег".

> На кожаный верх брички тяжело упала крупная капля дождя… другая, третья, четвёртая, и вдруг как будто кто-то забарабанил над нами, и вся окрестность огласилась равномерным шумом **падающего дождя**. [Л. Н. Толстой. Отрочество (1854)]
>
> Но вот однажды пришла зима, и с неба начал **падать ледяной дождь**, который мы до того ни разу не видели. [Татьяна Толстая. Ураган над Нью-Йорком // «Русская жизнь», 2012]
>
> Он проснулся с ощущением улетающего вещего сна. Из туч **падал ровный холодный дождь**. Куст, перевитый вьюнками, шелестел и слезился. [Александр Проханов. Господин Гексоген (2001)]
>
> **Снег** идёт, выпал, валит (разг.), сыплет, лежит, покрывает что-л. (землю ...), тает, сверкает, блестит, слепит глаза, **падает** ... (СЛОВАРЬ
> СОЧЕТАЕМОСТИ СЛОВ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА Под редакцией П. Н. ДЕНИСОВА, В. В. МОРКОВКИНА)

В данном случае *идет* и *падает* — синонимы, но у каждого свой оттенок смысла.
Не берусь говорить о равнозначности и равносильности, понятия *равнозначный* и  *равносильный* нечеткие.

Answer (score 1):

"Идёт" в сочетании с дождём или снегом указывает на *факт* природного явления (напр. на текущую метеорологическую ситуацию), "падает" указывает на его *созерцаемые особенности*. Нельзя сказать "на улице сейчас падает дождь" в прагматическом смысле (не поглядывая задумчиво в окно), это прозвучит излишне сентиментально. Это больше подходит для *книжного* описания наблюдений за характером дождя. Со снегом же можно обращаться свободнее, он может "падать" и вне прямой видимости - вероятно потому, что упоминание о нём в первую очередь ассоциируется со зрительным образом, зачастую приятным (это может быть приглашением выглянуть в окно или даже пойти погулять), а не с намоканием, как в случае дождя.

Comment: Мне кажется, снег воспринимается в первую очередь как вещество, а дождь — как атмосферное явление (а вода, падающая с неба, — это вторично), поэтому "снег падает" — нейтрально, а "дождь падает" — сентиментально (пользуясь Вашей терминологией).

Comment: Мы обычно воспринимаем  что-то  с помощью органов чувств: видим, слышим. В словаре же указано одинаковое толкование снега и дождя:  снег - твёрдые атмосферные осадки в виде звездообразных кристалликов или хлопьев; дождь -  атмосферные осадки в виде капель воды.

Comment: @Jasmin. Однако из снега лепят бабу, по снегу ездят и т.п. — в отличие от дождя. Для снега словарь дает второе значение: сплошная масса таких осадков, покрывающая какое-л. пространство. Глубокий с. Сугробы снега. Таяние снегов. Ездить по снегу.

Comment: Более того, снег как некая масса может образоваться не как атмосферные осадки (в холодильнике, например)

Comment: Разумеется, снег отличается от дождя (это твердое и жидкое состояния воды), но при этом у них есть общее название - атмосферные осадки. И речь идет о том, как мы называем этот процесс. Падает нечто хорошо видимое, и это относится к снежинкам. А вот отдельные капли дождя разглядеть сложно,  поэтому мы воспринимаем его как единую водяную массу, мелкодисперсную (моросит) или сплошную (льет). Мы же не говорим: снег моросит или льет, мы по-разному видим эти явления, поэтому и названия разные.

Comment: @Jasmin Вода в в жидком состоянии называется водой, а не дождем, то есть мы имеем два разных слова, а у слова снег такой пары нет.

Comment: И что с того, разве  об этом речь?  Ну не видим мы, как падают  капли дождя, поэтому  не говорим "опять сегодня падает дождь". Или Вы так говорите? В стихах можно сказать, там приветствуются свежие образы, необычные сочетания. Вот и статьи об этом пишут http://old.nsu.ru/education/virtual/cs012fateeva.pdf  Но если Вы уверяете нас в корректности сочетания, то хорошо бы сказать о  частотности его употребления  и об области применения.

Answer (score 1):

Выражение ***падает дождь*** непривычно для слуха и встречается очень редко, а вот капли дождя могут падать, но обычно с деревьев:

Неприятно ночевать в лесу, когда со всех деревьев  кругом **падают капли дождя** и везде кругом сыро, мокро! [П. К. Козлов. Географический дневник Тибетской экспедиции 1923-1926 гг. №2 (1924)].

Также падают капли росы, воды, крови (любой жидкости).

Почему? **Зрительно нам трудно увидеть в воздухе падающие водяные капли**, и часто о том, что идет мелкий дождь, мы узнаем по лужам. Поэтому д**ождь обычно идет, льет, моросит, а не падает.**

Зато мы хорошо **слышим,** как эти капли шумят при падении (отсюда шум падающего дождя).

А вот **отдельные снежинки мы видим хорошо,** они именно падают. Поэтом снег идет падает, сыплет. Кстати, дождь тоже сыплет.